# NSString between classes

Tags: xcode, class, nsstring

I need to pass a NSString between two Classes (from ViewController Class_A to ViewController Class_B) of my app, I have searched on StackOverflow but this is the simplified code of my situation:

Class_A.h

```
#import "Class_B.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *stringToPass;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *stringToPass;
-(NSString *)stringPassage:(id)sender;

@end
```

Class_A.m

```
- (NSString *)stringPassage:(id)sender{
    NSString *string = @"A FANTASTIC STRING!"; //here I define string INTO the - (NSString *) method
    NSLog(@"String to pass: %@",string);
    return string;
}
```

Class_B.h

```
#import "Class_A.h"
```

Class_B.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Class_A *Class_A_Instance = [[Class_A alloc] init];
    NSString *importedString = [Class_A_Instance stringPassage:self];
    [Class_A_Instance release];

    NSLog(@"Received String: %@",importedString);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Well, it works like a charm! When Class_B is loaded I can read in the log output "String to pass: A FANTASTIC STRING!" and "Received String: A FANTASTIC STRING!"; but if I change only this parts of code (I need it!):

Class_A.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    stringToPass = @"ANOTHER FANTASTIC STRING!";

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

- (NSString *)stringPassage:(id)sender{
    NSString *string = stringToPass; // here I must call the string FROM another method of Class_A (in this example from - (void)viewDidLoad
    NSLog(@"String to pass: %@",string);
    return string;
}
```

I can read in the log output "String to pass: (null)" and obv "Received String: (null)"; Its incredible because I can pass the global variable *stringToPass to every method of Class_A perfectly, except for this -(NSString *) method. So what is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let we have two viewControllers i.e FirstVC and the SecondVC. 
Make a string in SecondVC ,

```
@interface SecondVC : UIViewController { NSString *string2pass; }

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *string2pass;
```

In FirstVC when you are going to present SecondVC, pass the string as,

```
- (void)presentSecondView 
  { 
    SecondVC *secondVC = [[SecondVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil]; 

    secondVC.string2pass = @"this is a passing string";

   [self presentModalViewController:resView animated:YES];

  }    
- (void)viewDidLoad 
  { 
      NSString *string4mFirstVC = string2Pass 
  }
```

Comment: You forgot @synthesize string2pass; in SecondVC :) But this is a little confusing, I simply need to pass a string from FirstVC to SecondVC, why u define a NSString *string2pass in FirstVC and then define it again in secondVC.string2pass = @"this is a passing string"; ? I Wanna the string from the Class, not @"This is a passing string"...

Comment: 1-   string2pass is a define in SecondVC...

2-   so when we make object (*secondVC) of SecondVC on FirstVC , we  will set string2pass as secondVC.string2pass. 

3-   then when secondVC is loaded we can use this string2Pass string where ever we want, as i have use it string4mFirstVC.

Comment: Ah ok, perfect Baig! This is the solution, I have applied it to my situation, Where your FirstVC is my SecondVC and vice-versa... Thank u, I cant vote up because I have not yet reputation to do it. but I have given positive feedback! ;)

Answer (score 1):

`- (void)viewDidLoad` will not be called until after you call `-(NSString *)stringPassage`. Try moving `stringToPass = @"ANOTHER FANTASTIC STRING!";` into the `-(id)init` method of `Class_A`

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad, not viewWillLoad :) Well thanks, if I add a -(id)init in the Class_A I can pass the NSString variable INTO defined to Class_B, but unluckly I need to pass a mutable strings defined in other methods of Class_A

Comment: Oops that's what I meant!

If you want `Class_B` to know when `Class_A` has changed the string, then make `Class_B` a delegate of `Class_A` (take a look here: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html for example).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give an eye, but, again, why EVERY methods into Class_A receive the string defined into ViewDidLoad EXCEPT the - (NSString *) method that load (null) string; stringToPass its not a global variable? and ViewDidLoad doesn't load BEFORE - (NSString *)?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `init` method, not the `viewDidLoad` method.

If you add this to Class_A, you'll be closer:

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        stringToPass = @"ANOTHER FANTASTIC STRING!";   
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mprivat, I have already tried, and this works like a charm! But unluckly I need to pass mutable strings defined in other methods of Class_A, not in a -(id) init; why EVERY methods into Class_A receive the string defined into ViewDidLoad EXCEPT the - (NSString *) method that load (null) string? my stringToPass its not a global variable? and ViewDidLoad doesn't load BEFORE - (NSString *)?

Comment: That's because `viewDidLoad` doesn't actually get called until the view needs to be loaded (i.e. you are making the controller active on the window). At the time you are making your string transfer, if Controller A's view has not yet been shown, then it has not been loaded and therefore `viewDidLoad` has not been called and your string hasn't been initialized like you thought.

Comment: Well, and why if I add after ViewDidLoad a simple - (IBAction)action:(id)sender { NSLog(@"String to pass: %@",stringToPass); } I can read perfectly in the log output "String To Pass: ANOTHER FANTASTIC STRING!" just defined in ViewDidLoad? It seems ONLY -(NSString *) method can't receive my string :(

Comment: ok, so may be this will help you understand... Ask the question in reverse. In Class B, you call the method on an object ClassA that you just created on the previous line and called `init` and nothing else. Why would that method ever return anything other than `nil`?!

Comment: Exactly, but I'd understand this explanation if the stringToPass was (null) AFTER the Class_B loading and calling of method: my problem is that, as u can see, I have added a NSLog() INTO the - ( NSString *) method of Class_A and already here string is (null); so the problem is BEFORE the method call in Class_B